# How does a condiment become Fleishig?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Ive seen people label their ketchup or mustard or other condiments in their home as either meaty or milky or parve. How does a condiment's kosher status get changed?

Comment: Just a comment, it might be a way of keeping organized and avoiding problems, for example, using a meat knife to remove mustard, then using the same mustard in a dairy situation.

Comment: they also may have used it during cooking (zeia-steam) which is an issue that is why some people have different spices for both.

Comment: Offhand, a common scenario - take a spoonful of mustard, spread it on cooked meat; now the spoon is full of meat fat and meat pieces, and the spoon goes back into the mustard again for the second spreading. The jar of mustard is relatively small that after a few spreadings, it probably has the meaty taste, to the point where, perhaps, the meat is no longer less than 1/60 in volume?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a good practice as often kids may touch the ketchup bottle to the hamburger/pizza/mac&cheese when spreading ketchup on it, or their hands are messy. Stuff like that. (Especially if they have two refrigerators, you keep a bottle in each!)

Shulchan Aruch talks about separate salt *cellars*, but that's because people would dip their bread, cheese, or meat into the cellar, leaving behind little bits of meat. The commentaries there discuss, and reject, the idea that a salt *shaker* would really be milchig or fleishig.

Comment: RE: ketchup EWWW

Comment: Where can that be found in Sh"\`A?