# Can open kosher condiments (e.g., ketchup) found in a rented apartment be used?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

Let's say you rent an apartment and find open kosher condiments like ketchup in the fridge, can they be used?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/how-does-a-condiment-become-fleishig related

Comment: If your concern is that it’s out in the open for anyone to stick things into, this is probably a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98619/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is fruit sold in bulk at the store kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98619/is-fruit-sold-in-bulk-at-the-store-kosher)

Comment: Offhand, I think much depends on the nature of the container. E.g. a "tube" similar to a toothpaste tube which is certified kosher is highly unlikely to get non-kosher items stuck in it. A squeeze bottle of ketchup, probably is OK, also. But, if it's a type of container where one can stick a food-laden non-kosher utensil, then, that is more problematic.